# Downloading different test versions on Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

My Google user is currently on a closed Alpha list for an app *X*. So 
every time I open my Google Play Store I can download the current alpha version of app *X*.

The problem is: I now have to test the production version of *X* for a test. How can I "change" the version I'm willing to download? Do I have to remove myself from the "alpha testers" list so that I'm able to download the production version again?

Is there an easier way to just **switch** the version I want to download? I just can't find a way on my mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can switch to the production version is:
- opt-out of receiving the Alpha version from the opt-in page you got sent when you first joined the alpha

Alternative strategies other people use:
- you could use Multiple Android users. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user
If you have one user on the device which is in alpha, and one which isn't (each with a separate GMail account) then if one user installs the App you will get the Alpha version and if the other user installs the app you won't.